# Highlight in Adobe Reader X not working after update to 10.1.1

Tags: acrobat, adobe-reader

We have an application aimed at assisting people with reading difficulties. For that purpose we have written an Adobe Reader plugin which makes our application able to read text from PDF documents. While it reads it also highlights the words it is reading so that the user can keep up with it. However, after the 10.1.1 update of the Reader the highlighting no longer works.
The plugin was originally developed using Acrobat SDK 8.1, but the problem remained even after I upgraded to SDK 10. The highlighting is done using the AV-layer with the AVPageViewHighlightText() method.

We need to know if there is something in this recent update which breaks the highlight functionality, and if so, is it intentional?

PS: We are running with Protected Mode disabled since reading doesn’t work at all with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.
We are using the `void AVPageViewDrawNow(AVPageView pageView)` method to make sure that some changes are applied in certain cases. The behavior of this method seems to be different in Adobe Reader 10.1.1. Removing the call brought our highlighting back to life.